# PHP code for selection rules in Path Breadcrumbs not working

Tags: uri, breadcrumbs

Whenever I have this field filled, no breadcrumbs appear. And it even doesn't matter whether it returns true or false: I wrote 'return TRUE' there & there's no breadcrumbs.

Here's my export file:

```
$path_breadcrumb = new stdClass();
$path_breadcrumb->api_version = 1;
$path_breadcrumb->machine_name = 'construct';
$path_breadcrumb->name = 'construct';
$path_breadcrumb->path = 'node/%node';
$path_breadcrumb->data = array(
  'titles' => array(
    0 => '%node:field-one:0:pb-join:name',
  ),
  'paths' => array(
    0 => '%node:field-one:0:pb-join:url',
  ),
  'home' => 1,
  'translatable' => 0,
  'arguments' => array(
    'node' => array(
      'position' => 1,
      'argument' => 'entity_id:node',
      'settings' => array(
        'identifier' => 'Content: ID',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'access' => array(
    'plugins' => array(
      0 => array(
        'name' => 'node_type',
        'settings' => array(
          'type' => array(
            'vocab1' => 'vocab1',
          ),
        ),
        'context' => 'node',
        'not' => FALSE,
      ),
      1 => array(
        'name' => 'php',
        'settings' => array(
          'description' => 'choice',
          'php' => 'return TRUE',
        ),
        'not' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
    'logic' => 'or',
  ),
);
$path_breadcrumb->weight = 8;
```

Comment: Does it tell you to wrap your PHP in <?php ?> tags? Did you try with those or without those?

Comment: I used no tags (as it's said in the UI)